# Where to put javascript functionality when certain Redux actions are thrown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following Redux Reducer to handle the offset of an infinite scroll component:

```
const offset = handleActions(
  {
    [questionListTypes.ON_QUESTIONS_SCROLL]: state => state + QuestionsLoadChunkTotal,
    [combineActions(questionListTypes.RESET_QUESTIONS_OFFSET)]: () => {
      document.getElementById('question-list-infinite-scroll').scrollTop = 0;
      return 0;
    },
  },
  0,
);
```

When the offset of the component resets I want to scroll the HTML element to the top. I have added the following line in the reducer to handle this:

```
document.getElementById('question-list-infinite-scroll').scrollTop = 0;
```

This doesn't feel right to me to put it here because it has nothing to do with my state. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: This seems very strange to me. First of all, Redux is for global state. Why is Redux being used for this? Second, in React you shouldn't ever have to directly access HTML elements. There is a React way to do everything.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Redux middleware, which purpose is to handle side effects.

It receives every action that goes through and enables us to have any side effect.

```js
const scrollReseter = store => next => action => {
  next(action);
  if (action.type === combineActions(questionListTypes.RESET_QUESTIONS_OFFSET)) {
    document.getElementById('question-list-infinite-scroll').scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

See https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware/

Comment: Does this have any impact on the performance? I have managed to make this work but i have to check on a lot of types. This means it has to do all these checks every time a new action is thrown?

Comment: You mean you have a lot of conditions to test to know if you have to scroll to top ? Or just that you’re filtering one specific action type out of many ?

Comment: Reducers also trigger on every action and run your action type check conditionals, this is not unique to middleware. Also, Redux copies the state every time you perform a mutation. I suggest profiling your performance if this worries you. You can't assume that there is an issue until you actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get a reference to the DOM element and use an effect to manipulate that element when a certain value in the state changes.

Here is an example using local state:

```js
const App = () => {
  //this would be data that comes from state
  //  maybe with useSelector or with connect
  const [scrollToTop, setScrollToTop] = React.useState(0);
  //create a ref to the element you want to scroll
  const scrollRef = React.useRef();
  //this would be an action that would set scrollToTop with a new
  //  value
  const goToTop = () => setScrollToTop((val) => val + 1);
  //this is an effect that runs every time scrollToTop changes
  //  it will run on mount as well so when scrollToTop is 0 it
  //  does nothing
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollToTop) {
      scrollRef.current.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }, [scrollToTop]);
  return (
    <div
      ref={scrollRef}
      style={{ maxHeight: '250px', overflow: 'scroll' }}
    >
      {[...new Array(10)].map((_, key) => (
        <h1
          key={key}
          onClick={goToTop}
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        >
          click to scroll to top
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```